# Why is POST action losing model values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a ViewModel which I'm trying to post back to save in the DB. While the ViewModel is getting the values set in the `//GET Create(int id)` it is losing some of them by the time it gets to the `//POST Create ()`. The `GoalLevel` and `GoalTitle` are being passed through OK, but the `ActorId` and `ProjectId` are being lost and even though the debugger is going through the `if (Model.State.IsValid)` block, the values that are going through aren't being saved to the DB. The redirect then falls over, because I've no longer got a valid `ProjectId` to pass to the URL.

I'm sure it's something obvious if you know what you're doing!

**CONTROLLER**

```
  // GET: UseCases/Create

    public ActionResult Create(int id)

    {

        ViewBag.projectId = id;

        //Populate the ViewModel
        UserGoalsStepViewModel model = new UserGoalsStepViewModel()
        {
            ProjectId = id,
            ActorList = new SelectList(db.Actors.Where(a => a.projectID == id), "id", "Title"),

        };

        return View(model);
    }

    // POST: UseCases/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ProjectId,ActorId,GoalTitle,Level")] UserGoalsStepViewModel model)
    {




        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            //Create a use case object to map to, which can then be saved in the DB

            UseCase uc = new UseCase();
            uc.ProjectID = model.ProjectId;
            uc.ActorID = model.ActorId;
            uc.Level = (Level)model.Level;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = model.ProjectId });
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
 public class UserGoalsStepViewModel
    {
        public enum GoalLevel
        {
            Summary, UserGoal, SubGoal,
        }

            public int ProjectId { get; set; }
            public int ActorId { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Actor Title")]    
            public SelectList ActorList { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Goal Title")]
            public string GoalTitle { get; set; }
            public GoalLevel Level { get; set; }

            public UserGoalsStepViewModel ()
            {

            }


    }
```

**VIEW**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>UseCase</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ActorList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ActorList, Model.ActorList, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ActorList, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GoalTitle, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GoalTitle, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GoalTitle, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Level, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Level, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Level, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**UPDATED POST METHOD WHICH IS STILL GIVING AN ERROR AND NOT SAVING TO DB**

After amends, I'm now getting this error `Message=The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.UseCase_dbo.Actor_ActorID". The conflict occurred in database "JustSpecIt", table "dbo.Actor", column 'ID'` when attempting to save to DB.

Here is relevant bit of updated POST method:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                //Create a use case object to map to, which can then be saved in the DB

                UseCase uc = new UseCase();
                uc.ProjectID = model.ProjectId;
                uc.ActorID = model.ActorId;
                uc.Title = model.GoalTitle;
                uc.Level = (Level)model.Level;
                db.UseCases.Add(uc);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = model.ProjectId });
            }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to store the values for ProjectId and ActorId as Hidden Inputs on your form so that they can be included in the posted values sent back to your controller action.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
 {
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ProjectId)
     @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ActorId)
     ...
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I hadn't realised that if I didn't have something holding the model value in the view then it would be lost when posting - lesson learned! I'm still having an issue with saving to the database, I'm getting this exception `
`Message=The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.UseCase_dbo.Actor_ActorID". The conflict occurred in database "JustSpecIt", table "dbo.Actor", column 'ID'` - I've added an update to the post above

Comment: In fact, I see why I'm getting the FK error, the ActorId is still not getting posted. I'll do some further investigation - I suspect it's something to do with the SelectList

Comment: The reason that it is not getting passed is because your model property is called ActorList, so instead of passing a value named ActorId to your action you are passing a value named ActorList.

Comment: You're right - I had the select list messed up. I actually ended up refactoring a bit and replaced ActorId in my ViewModel with `SelectedActorId`, then changed my DDL to `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedActorId, Model.ActorList, new { @class = "form-control" })` and my POST action to `uc.ActorID = model.SelectedActorId;`

Comment: Excellent, glad that I could help in pointing you in the right direction.